# publish asp.net application localy in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis

i'm trying to publish asp.net app localy on my computer:

In the iis i right-click the "sites" and selected "Add website"
In site name i wrote: www.mysite.com
Physical path: i created new folder named "www" on my c driver
Type: http
IP address: all unassigned
port:80
host name: www.mysite.com

in visual studio:
I selected build-> publish
get the message that both the built and the publish succeeded.
In "select publish target" i pressed "custom" and created new profile
publish method: file system
target location: c:\www

and still when i write the url in chrome or explorer i get url not found (the computer is not connected to the internet)
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you go to http://localhost  or http://127.0.0.1?

Comment: also in c:\www do you have a default.htm/default.html/index.htm/index.html?

Comment: in www\mysite i have Default.htm file.
The file is fine - i can open it with the browser and it work.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager --> Application Pools

check if your added website application pool status has been started or not?

Also check whether your .NET Framework version is 4.0 or not for added website in application pool? If not double click and change the options.

Comment: In iis after selecting my site on the right side of the window under "Manage website" the "start" button is greyed and the "restat" is green.
I did press "restart" but it probaby was already working.

Comment: Check under Application pool if your website has correct .Net Framework version or not. Try changing the option by double clicking on the website in Application pool and change it to v4.0

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you're not using `http://localhost`, then DNS is missing.

You need to map whatever "web site name" (`www.mysite.com`) you used to:

- your local loopback ip, `127.0.0.1`, **or**;
- whatever local IP your router/dhcp service provided your local machine), **or**;
- if you want to be fancy and assign multiple IPs to your machine, then assign one to the site

Finally, map any of the above to your [`hosts` file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958812.aspx).

Hth..

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote
If i write http://localhost the browser goes to the default.
I want to be able to write www.mysite.com and then the browser will
refer to asp.net application

Comment: @cabeloblanco As above, `DNS` (aka "name resolution") is missing. Link above explains in detail what you need to do **locally** - obviously, if this is for public consumption, then you need to have, as stated, proper `DNS` setup.

Comment: in my HOSTS file i wrote the following:
#
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost
# 127.0.0.1 www.mysite.com